# Building php from source

Tags: php, makefile

I've downloaded sources of php. then I've done

```
./configure \
--prefix=/opt/php-5.2 \
--with-config-file-path=/opt/php-5.2 \
--with-pdo-pgsql \
--with-zlib-dir \
--with-freetype-dir \
--enable-mbstring \
--with-libxml-dir=/usr \
--enable-soap \
--enable-calendar \
--with-curl=/usr/bin \
--with-mcrypt \
--with-zlib \
--with-gd \
--with-pgsql \
--disable-rpath \
--enable-inline-optimization \
--with-zlib \
--enable-sockets \
--enable-sysvsem \
--enable-sysvshm \
--enable-pcntl \
--enable-mbregex \
--with-mhash \
--enable-zip \
--with-pcre-regex \
--with-mysql \
--with-pdo-mysql \
--with-mysqli \
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
--with-png-dir=/usr \
--enable-gd-native-ttf \
--with-openssl \
--enable-ftp \
--with-imap \
--with-imap-ssl \
--with-kerberos \
--with-gettext \
--enable-cli \
--enable-fastcgi \
--enable-discard-path \
--enable-force-cgi-redirect \
--enable-cgi
```

and when I try to do `make`, I'm getting the following error:

> make: *** No rule to make target `@OURREGEX@', needed by`PHP_PROGS'. 
>   Stop.

Comment: What's with the `-dir` options without a directory?

Comment: I dont know, just copied it.

Comment: You just copied someone else's configure options? Why do you need to compile php if you aren't configuring your own build? What happens when you just run `./configure`?

Comment: The same. 
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
When I go to src dir 
make: *** No rule to make target `@OURREGEX@', needed by `PHP_PROGS'.  Stop.

Comment: I need to compile my own php because I need few versions(5.2 in cgi mode and 5.3) on one machine 5.3 is currently installed.

Comment: It's just as if you are using, as Makefile, a file that needs to be preprocessed into a Makefile.